# Regenerate Webservice client stubs if a class was modified?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a web service that I've been calling for a while with a java client.

I call a certain class in that web-service with no issues.

If a setter and a getter were suddenly added to that class in the web service, but I do **not** need to use the new getter and setter, should I still regenerate my client stubs with axis or would the client still work and retrieve data from the old unmodified getter of that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition of new operations do not affect clients and do not require regeneration of client stubs. So if the old method is there and the types have not changed you could still invoke the method without any regeneration. After all it is just a soap request for the specific method.
To access the new methods of course you have to regenerate.
Check this for compatible changes in web services: [ws back-compatible](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/ws-soa-backcomp/)